# Detecting removed SD-Card - C - ARM -

Tags: c, arm, sd-card, stm32f4, fatfs

how it is possible to detect the removed SD-Card, and after that how it is possible to detect the inserting and do the re-mounting? 
I am working at STM32-F401 in C and with fatfs. Detecting incorrect mounting or removed card is relatively easy:

```
fresult1 = f_mount(&myFATAFS, SDPath, 1)
while(FR_OK != fresult1){
     /*Watch out for sd-card and if you find one try to mount*/
     ...
}
```

And now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it from this level. SD interface has line CD - CardDetect. You should connect it to GPIO and test it in the timer interrupt (EXTI interrupts are not good for that as debouncing is needed)

Comment: And there is no other (soft) way to get this information?

Comment: Only when IO operation will fail :)